# React Typescript - Context in react component class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a react typescript app with create react app. I now want to have a context which I want accessible across all my components:

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext<{name: string}>({name: 'Foo'});
```

The context is linked to the state of the main app component. This state does change and therefore the value of context should also change for the components.

```
<UserContext.Provider value={this.state}>
    <MainPage/>
</UserContext.Provider>
```

I have followed the doc string suggestion for how to set up in context in a component and so have this:

```
class MainPage extends React.Component {
   static contextType = UserContext;
   context!: React.ContextType<typeof UserContext>;

   public render() {
       return <div>{this.context.name}</div>
   }
}
```

However `this.context.name` is always null. I have placed a div with it's value linked to `this.state` in *the app component* and that does show the value unlike the context. I am struggling as the code works when written in raw react / create-react-app and I was under the components where the same in `@types/react`?

Does anyone know how to implement context inside a component class in typescript?

Comment: @types/react doesn't behave differently. It has no runtime behaviour it is just a declaration file that is used to statically check the code for errors.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looks like the type parameter of your `UserContext` is slightly wrong. You need to remove the `typeof`.

so `React.createContext<{ name: string }>` instead of `React.createContext<typeof { name: string }>`

This works for me:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const UserContext = React.createContext<{ name: string }>({ name: 'test' });

export class MainPage extends React.Component<undefined, undefined> {
  static contextType = UserContext;
  context!: React.ContextType<typeof UserContext>;

  public render() {
    return <div>{this.context.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is correct that there should not be a `typeof` in front of the interface. I made that mistake when writing this question because I was simplifying a more complex interface that actually exists there. So having removed the typeof the context still doesn't work??? However if I copy your code above my reactapp does not compile as it does not like the export infront of the class without a default keyword AND it also does not like the `undefined` as type arguments of type arguments. What version are you using as my version may not like context?

Comment: what errors are you getting? are they typescript errors, or lint errors

Comment: i was just doing it on codesandbox, just checked that the types worked, but didnt go further than that

Comment: for ts 3.7 and above it should be done like this

`static contextType = SampleContext;`
`declare context: ContextType<typeof SampleContext>`